# Photo Competition 2021-09-20: Metal on metal

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Metal on metal

All things metallic. Gears, heavy machinery, drilling metal, cutting metal...

This theme was suggested by [spikey_richie](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/94572/spikey-richie).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/126200/photo-competition-2021-09-20-metal-on-metal?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on October 4, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Heavy Metal

Six-hundred tons (1.2 million pounds or 544,310 kilograms) of Union Pacific 'Big Boy' locomotive #4014 rests on one-hundred-sixty pound rail¹ during an August 26, 2020 stop in Gurdon, Arkansas as it waits to stretch its legs again once the green light is lit.

[image: Heavy Metal]
<sub>Canon EOS 5D Mark IV + EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II @ 200mm. ISO 100, f/3.5, 1/400.</sub>

The locomotive, manufactured in 1941, was restored to operating condition in 2019 after spending over fifty years on static display at the RailGiants Train Museum in Southern California. Following several tours of various parts of the Union Pacific system in the Spring, Summer, and Fall of 2019 to celebrate the 150th Anniversary of the completion of the first transcontinental railroad connecting the east and west coasts of the United States, #4014 did not make any public appearances during 2020.

Union Pacific took #4014 out again for a six week tour in the late Summer of 2021 with stops in Nebraska, Kansas, Missouri, Kansa, Oklahoma, Texas, Louisiana, Texas, Arkansas, Missouri, Illinois, Missouri, Kansas, Colorado, and then back home to Cheyenne, Wyoming.

<sub>¹ 160 pound rail is so called because it weighs 160 pounds per linear yard (72.6 kg per 0.914 m).</sub>

Answer (score 7):

[image: underneath the beehive]

## Underneath the beehive

Seen at Kew Gardens. A metal construction that you can walk into, around and under. It has a glass floor that collects rainwater. A view from underneath.


Lumix Panasonic gx80


f: 6.3

ss:1/320

iso:200

14 mm

Answer (score 5):

**The Metal Underside**

[image: Brooklyn Bridge Metal Underside]

The underside of the Brooklyn Bridge covered in metal back in January 2011.

Canon EOS 400D, Tokina 11-16mm @ 11mm, f/5, 1/125 second, ISO 400.

Answer (score 4):

### Fish Machine

[image]

It's a machine that was probably used in the sardine canning industry in Monterey

Cannery Row, Monterey CA July 5th 2021

D500 with Nikkor 18-140

1/160, f/4.5, ISO2851

Answer (score 4):

### Sunset Statues

[image]

Congregation Shir Hadash July 19th 2021

D500 with Sigma 150-600

f/5.6, 1/800, ISO 2851

Answer (score 4):

**Rolling Metal**

[image: N Train rolling into Brooklyn]

A guy watching hundreds of tons of metal rolling into Brooklyn off the Manhattan Bridge around dusk on a warm winter evening a in 2015.

Canon EOS 6D, 24-105mm @ 97mm, f/4, 1/10 second, ISO 400

Answer (score 3):

**Man in the mirror**

[image: Man in the mirror]

This is an image taken at Yorkshire Sculpture Park in the UK, near Wakefield. It's part of an art installation, but I can't find the artist. The 2 figures are constructed from aluminium oven trays (hopefully recycled!). I like this shot the best, it's quite thought-provoking.

Olympus OMD E-10.3, 25mm Lumix prime ƒ/1.8, 1/4000 (it was a bright day) ISO 200.

Answer (score 3):

### Metal Miner

[image]

Almaden Quicksilver Mining Museum 9/4/2021

D500 with Nikkor 18-140
f/4, 1/1600, ISO 1425

Answer (score 2):

### Big Boy in Motion

Restored Union Pacific 'Big Boy' #4014 rolls past the passenger platform in Gurdon, Arkansas as it starts its train moving again after a short stop the morning of August 26, 2021 during the Fall, 2021 tour of the southeastern portions of the Union Pacific Railroad system.

There's shiny bare metal, metal coated in various lubricants, metal painted in flat graphite, glossy black, metal knobs, handles, and levers painted red, naturally colored brass, as well as rust coated rails.

[image]
<sub>Canon EIS 5D Mark III + EF 24-105mm f/4 L IS @ 24mm. ISO 100, f/6.3, 1/160.</sub>

The locomotive, manufactured in 1941, was restored to operating condition in 2019 after spending over fifty years on static display at the RailGiants Train Museum in Southern California between 1961 and 2013. Following several tours of various parts of the Union Pacific system in the Spring, Summer, and Fall of 2019 to celebrate the 150th Anniversary of the completion of the first transcontinental railroad connecting the east and west coasts of the United States, #4014 did not make any public appearances during 2020.

Union Pacific took #4014 out again for a six week tour in the late Summer of 2021 with stops along a route through Nebraska, Kansas, Missouri, Kansas, Oklahoma, Texas, Louisiana, Texas, Arkansas, Missouri, Illinois, Missouri, Kansas, Colorado, and then back home to Cheyenne, Wyoming. Major cities visited included Kansas City, Fort Worth, Houston, New Orleans, St. Louis, and Denver.

Answer (score 2):

### The Bridge

[image: Photo submission]
<sub>Canon Rebel T7 + Canon EF 70-300mm f/4-5.6 IS USM @ 70mm.  ISO 400, 1/40, f/7.1</sub>

A metal-grate footbridge in a local park near Cincinnati, Ohio.  My roommate and I come to this park occasionally with our cameras to see what we capture that we haven't before.